# mouse click x and y cords displaying NULL values - onclick event handling

Tags: javascript, onclick, event-handling

Trying to display the x and y values of a mouse click. The problem: I am always getting 0,0. I think the property `event.currentTarget` is not being detected by the script.

**The first function calculates the relative value of the parent's element and subtracts I.E. padding, border, and scroll.**

```
// get the position of click - 
function getPosition(el) {
  var xPosition = 0;
  var yPosition = 0;
 
  while (el) {
    if (el.nodeName == "BODY") {
      // deal with browser quirks with body/window/document and page scroll
      var xScrollPos = el.scrollLeft || document.documentElement.scrollLeft;
      var yScrollPos = el.scrollTop || document.documentElement.scrollTop;
 
      xPosition += (el.offsetLeft - xScrollPos + el.clientLeft);
      yPosition += (el.offsetTop - yScrollPos + el.clientTop);
    } else {
      xPosition += (el.offsetLeft - el.scrollLeft + el.clientLeft);
      yPosition += (el.offsetTop - el.scrollTop + el.clientTop);
    }
 
    el = el.offsetParent;
  }
  return {
    x: xPosition,
    y: yPosition,
    a: "hahah",
  };
}

// Set up event handlers according to standards
window.addEventListener("load", function(){
  document.addEventListener("click", handleClick);
});

function handleClick(event, x, y) {
    var el = event.CurrentTarget;
    posOb = getPosition(event.CurrentTarget);
 alert("x:" + posOb.x + ", y:" + posOb.y);
}
```

Comment: So to be clear, you're not trying to get the coordinates of the click itself, you're trying to get the top-left corner of the element that was clicked? Or...? (You're not using the coordinates from the `event` object, so...)

Comment: I am trying to get the coordinates of the click x and y NOT the corner of the element. Can you please explain what you mean by not using the cord from the event object. New to Js

Comment: The [click `event` object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/Events/click) has properties that give you the coordinates where the click occurred, but you are not using those properties anywhere, you only use the `event.currentTarget` - which should have a lowercase "c" (your use of an uppercase "C" is probably why you always get (0,0), because uppercase "C" `.CurrentTarget` is undefined). You want to look into `event.screenX`, `event.screenY`, `event.clientX`, and `event.clientY`.

Comment: Changing the currentTarget to lowercase only displays NaN value. Doesn't work. With regards to clientX and clientY, doesn't these properties return the top left corner coordinates of the element i.e. the relative value of x and y to the parent container instead of being relative to the screen??

Comment: Lowercase "c" is definitely correct for `.currentTarget` - the fact that you then get `NaN` is actually a *good* sign, because it means the code inside the while loop is now actually being executed, whereas before it was not (because with the uppercase "C" `el` was undefined). So now you can move on to fixing that code in the while loop. Anyway, the click event's `.clientX` and `.clientY` don't return top-left corner (unless you click there), they are coordinates of where the mouse was. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent/clientX

Comment: I was reading this article which points out, "The problem is this. The X and Y position returned by clientX and clientY is relative to the element you clicked on"... https://www.kirupa.com/html5/getting_mouse_click_position.htm 

Otherwise JUST using clientX and clientY makes the job easy.

Comment: Well yes, it's relative to the clicked element, but you have to start somewhere. The article you linked to says "[the `getPosition()` function] provides you with the additional pieces of information needed to make your existing calculations involving clientX and clientY complete." - in other words, you do still need the event `clientX` and `clientY`, and other parts of that article say so too. (And my central point here is that your current code doesn't use the event's coordinates at all.)

Comment: Ohh, I get it now.I need the clientX and ClientY values to identify the x and y cords relative to the element clicked on and ADD the xPosition and the yPosition (which have the padding, border and scroll offsets) to reach the correct coordinates of moue clicked, perhaps....yes?

Comment: Yes, that sounds right. (I didn't make any effort to check if the calculations in the `getPosition()` function are correct, but in a general sense that's what it is supposed to do.)

Comment: I fixed the NaN issue. I ran a test to see if clientX value was different from the true x value calculated, they're not. Probably have to look into calculations again. ugh.